# Conflict in django models . How to debug?

Tags: django

This is the error I get .

```
   auth.permission: Accessor for field 'content_type' clashes with related field 'ContentType.permission_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'content_type'.
    permissions.permission: Accessor for field 'table' clashes with related field 'ContentType.permission_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'table'.
```

This is my model .

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from maps.models import  Sdr_Layer

class Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    table = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    permi = models.IntegerField()
```

Can someone explain to me what the error means and how to remove it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you create a `ForeignKey` linking to another model, there is a backward relationship automatically created on that *to* model. In your case on `permissions.Permission` the `ForeignKey` to `ContentType` means there will be a manager added to `ContentType` called `permission_set` that will allow access back to `permissions.Permission` objects that link to it.

The reason why it does not work is that it's ambiguous whether the backward relationship manager `permission_set` should refer to your `permissions.Permission` model, or the built-in `auth.Permission` model. (Both have a `ForeignKey` to `ContentType`, and so a backward relationship manager is created for both.)

To resolve this problem, you must use the `related_name` parameter to `ForeignKey`. This allows your to override the default `FOO_set` name, with your own. e.g.:

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    table = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='custom_permission_set') 
    permi = models.IntegerField()
```